# Does monodis tool from mono work against Microsoft .NET assemblies?

Tags: mono, ildasm

I know the monodis tool does the same thing for Mono that ILDASM does for Microsoft .NET. But is the monodis tool compatible with .NET in that it would work against a Microsoft .NET assembly because it works to the same file layout as Microsoft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does. Also, it's trivial to check, why did you even bother asking this?